# Format ptime object for string output

Tags: c++, boost, datetime-format

I am trying to find away to simply convert a ptime object in boost C++ into a string, using a predefined format.

Something following this logic.

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
ptime timeObj = time_from_string("2002-01-20 23:59:59");
timeObj.format("%m %d");
string result = timeObj.toString();
```

However, that closest I can find is to use a date_facet/time_facet to format the time, then output it to a stream, as in this example from boost: 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.date_facet

```
//example to customize output to be "LongWeekday LongMonthname day, year"
//                                  "%A %b %d, %Y"
date d(2005,Jun,25);
date_facet* facet(new date_facet("%A %B %d, %Y"));
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));
std::cout << d << std::endl;
// "Saturday June 25, 2005"
```

I would love to know if there is an easier way to do this.
Thanks in advance :)